# Cannot put QAbstractListModel object as one class's property

Tags: qt, qobject, qabstractlistmodel

My code looks like so:

```
class Wrapper: public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(PeopleListModel & list READ list)
public:
  PeopleListModel & list() {
    return list_;
  }  

private:
  PeopleListModel list_;  
};
```

And PeopleListModel is a subclass of QAbstractListModel.

But I got compilation error:

```
       ^
In file included from plugin.cpp:131:0:
plugin.moc: In member function ‘virtual int Wrapper::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)’:
plugin.moc:184:52: error: cannot declare pointer to ‘class PeopleListModel&’
         case 0: *reinterpret_cast< PeopleListModel&*>(_v) = list(); break;
                                                    ^
In file included from ../../../../Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qnamespace.h:45:0,
                 from ../../../../Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:45,
                 from ../../../../Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:48,
                 from ../../../../Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qplugin.h:45,
                 from ../../../../Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64/include/QtQml/qqmlextensionplugin.h:45,
                 from ../../../../Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64/include/QtQml/QQmlExtensionPlugin:1,
                 from plugin.cpp:1:
../../../../Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qabstractitemmodel.h: In member function ‘PeopleListModel& PeopleListModel::operator=(const PeopleListModel&)’:
../../../../Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:967:12: error: ‘QAbstractListModel& QAbstractListModel::operator=(const QAbstractListModel&)’ is private
     Class &operator=(const Class &) Q_DECL_EQ_DELETE;
            ^
../../../../Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qabstractitemmodel.h:479:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘Q_DISABLE_COPY’
     Q_DISABLE_COPY(QAbstractListModel)
     ^
plugin.cpp:32:7: error: within this context
 class PeopleListModel : public QAbstractListModel {
       ^
In file included from plugin.cpp:131:0:
plugin.moc: In member function ‘virtual int Wrapper::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)’:
plugin.moc:184:59: note: synthesized method ‘PeopleListModel& PeopleListModel::operator=(const PeopleListModel&)’ first required here 
         case 0: *reinterpret_cast< PeopleListModel&*>(_v) = list(); break;
                                                           ^
make: *** [plugin.o] Error 1
```

Comment: try to declare property as an object, not a reference. Reference should be initialized immediately, and probably moc somewhere does it not.

Comment: Also properties should be copyable classes. While `Q_DISABLE_COPY(QAbstractListModel)` macro ( `QAbstractListModel` — base class for your `PeopleListModel` I assume) disallows that.

Comment: I use property instead of reference at first, but still get the above error.  I just want to expose one class's property to QML, this property(here is a listmodel) could offer data to my listview on qml.

Comment: well still problem with copying remains. Moc tries to assign value to your property and uses operator=. Which is private cause of `Q_DISABLE_COPY` macro.

Comment: Well, i'll try to explain it other way: QObject instances can't be copied anyways. So you have to include any subclasses of it in class, not to declare them as properties. See documentation of QObject, section "No copy constructor or assignment operator":
"QObject has neither a copy constructor nor an assignment operator. This is by design."

Comment: It will work with pointer (`PeopleListModel* list_;`).

Comment: @PavelStrakhov I tried pointer before, but do not know how to use it in qml. Does qml recognize the pointer or object automatically? Could you give me an example?